# How to hide or minimize X11 window from console?

Tags: linux, console, xorg

Window is full-screen and grabs everything.
New windows are appearing behind it.

I cannot just kill that application.

I'm logged in as root remotely through the SSH.

Expecting something like that:

```
$ xcontrol
> ls
window id: PID:   Window class:    Window name:    ...
111       1122   Vncviewer ..
222       1133    .. .            google-chrome ...
> minimize 111
> restore 111
> hide 222
> unhide 222
> move 111 by (10,-20)
> q
$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to control windows and the desktop from the command line.
(If you are logging in via SSH or virtual console, you probably have to set DISPLAY to :0 first.)  For instance:

```
## List windows
wmctrl -l
## Put the window (find window id in above list) below other windows:
wmctrl -i -r 0x04800004 -b add,below
## Remove maximization:
wmctrl -i -r 0x04800004 -b remove,maximized_horz,maximized_vert
```

I haven't found out how to minimize one window with wmctrl, but you can show the desktop (i.e., minimize all windows) with

```
wmctrl -k on
```

Comment: wmctrl finds the window, but it resists to all that commands. Does it work for, for example, OpenGL or some other enhanced windows?

Comment: wmctrl is supposed to work with EWMH/NetWM compatible X window managers.  The web page lists WMs known to work.  Which WM are you using?

Comment: inconify feature for wmctrl is comming in a future release. the author added a -Y flag for that (commited in github).

Comment: what if it's not a "window" exactly?  it doesn't appear in `wmctrl -l`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) can help you.

Comment: Yes! see http://askubuntu.com/questions/4876/can-i-minimize-a-window-from-the-command-line

Comment: `xdotool selectwindow` and `xdotool windowunmap $window_id` worked great

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`xdotool search --name '^fzf_kitty$' windowunmap`

`xdotool search --name '^fzf_kitty$' windowmap`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).