# Console tool to control x windows

Tags: linux, xorg, console

I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/186748/how-to-hide-or-minimize-x11-window-from-console), but it's answers are not good enough for me, because I do not have a window manager on my system.

Is there a console tool that can hide windows?

**EDIT**
I am using `xwininfo` to get information about the window. It gives window id, and some additional stuff. This id should be enough to do any operation with the window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is, but have you tried WMCTRL? Just installed it, haven't tried it - give it a go :) (It's in the Debian Wheezy repos, don't know which distro you're using)
GL

Comment: I can not use it, because it requires a window manager. I am using fedora 9