# SSH tunnel and VNC

Tags: terminal, ssh-tunnel, vnc-viewer

I'm using Porteus 3.2.2 to connect to a VNC server in the internet through a SSH tunnel, and I'm trying to automate it as much as possible.

I have this script that creates the tunnel and keeps it open, but I would like to tweak it a little bit.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#create SSH tunnel
ssh -L 5901:192.168.1.200:5901 -t user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'vncserver -geometry 1280x800; /bin/bash'

#open vncviewer
vncviewer -fullscreen localhost:5901

exit 0
```

---

- I would like it to minimize the terminal window after logging in to the server.
- Also AFTER login successfully, I would like it to open vncviewer with no terminal window, and with the options above.

The way I have the script doesn't work because it only launches after the ssh tunnel closes. And I can't use '&' to send the ssh tunnel to background. Also, if I put vncviewer before the SSH tunnel and send it to background I can't use the options...

Any help here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use '&'?

Comment: Because SSH tunneling doesn't allow it... Only vncviewer, but I just want to launch vncviewer AFTER the SSH tunnel is running...

Comment: ??? Making background any task is bash's job, so any command can be put to background. What does it mean "_SSH tunneling doesn't allow it_"? Does It say `permission denied` or what?

Comment: It just says that it can't be backgrounded... I don't know if it is because it asks a password...

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `-f` option to your SSH command line should get you closer to what you want: it causes the ssh client to go to the background, but only after the connection has been established and any password requests have been fulfilled, allowing `vncviewer` to start once the SSH connection has been established.

If starting the VNC server at the remote system takes a noticeable amount of time, you might want to add `sleep <some number of seconds>` between the `ssh` command line and the `vncviewer` command line, to allow the VNC server to complete start-up before `vncviewer` attempts to connect to it.

Minimizing the terminal window would require sending a "minimize/iconify this window" command to the window manager of your local desktop environment. The details will depend on the type of desktop environment you're using, but in general, the commands `wmctrl` or `xdotool` might be able to do it.

Please see: 
[How to hide or minimize X11 window from console?](https://superuser.com/questions/186748/how-to-hide-or-minimize-x11-window-from-console)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try the -f flag, it sounds just like what I need...

Comment: Thanks, man. That did the trick! Used the -f flag and after successful ssh login, it sets itself to background leaving the tunnel open, after which it launches vncviewer with all the options i want. As for minimizing the window, i think i won't bother with that for now...